# z-index is not making the slider under header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am having issues with a WordPress template that has not allowed me to place the slider underneath the header ID.

I have looked everywhere but everything I do just does not work.

Header CSS

```
#header {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    width: 100%;
    height: 212px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```

Slider main CSS

```
#contback {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:0;
    position: relative;
}
```

html is too long to post here so i'll just post the main parts.

```
!-- ### BODY #### -->
<body class="home page page-id-11 page-template-default logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support"> 

<!-- Header -->
<div id="header">
    <div class="header-row fixed">  

        <div id="logo">
            <a href="http://radiobreakout.com.au"><img src="http://radiobreakout.com.au/wp-content/themes/beaton/images/logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
        </div><!-- end #logo -->


    <div id="evhead">
        <div class="evhead-cont">
            <a href="http://radiobreakout.com.au/?event=radio-breakout">
                <div class="evhead-bg"></div>
                <img src="http://radiobreakout.com.au/wp-content/themes/beaton/images/no-cover/evhead.png" alt="no-cover" />
                <div class="evhead-date">01 Jan</div>
                <div class="evhead-week">Friday</div>
                <div class="evhead-loc"><span></span></div>
            </a>
        </div><!-- end .evhead-cont -->
    </div><!-- end #evhead -->    
    </div><!-- end .header-row fixed -->

    <div id="menu">
    <div class="menu-row">

<div id="wizemenu" class="menu-main-container"><ul class="megamenu"><li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-11 current_page_item active"><a href="http://radiobreakout.com.au/">Home</a></li>
</ul></div> 
    </div><!-- end .menu-row -->
    </div><!-- end #menu -->
</div><!-- end #header -->



<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("#radio").flashradio({
        themecolor: "#00cab6",
        channelurls: "163.47.16.24:8000/stream",
        scroll: "AUTO",
        autoplay: "TRUE",
        html5chrome: "TRUE",
        debug: "TRUE",
        startvolume: "100"
    });

    $(".radio-wz-open-hidden").click(function() {
        $("#radio-wz #radio-wz-col").slideToggle({
            direction: "up"
        }, 100);
        $(this).toggleClass("clientsClose");
    });
    $("#radio-wz-col").show();

    function mouseHandler(e) {
        if ($(this).hasClass("radio-wz-hidden-open")) {
            $(this).removeClass("radio-wz-hidden-open");
        } else {
            $(".radio-wz-hidden-open").removeClass("radio-wz-hidden-open");
            $(this).addClass("radio-wz-hidden-open");
        }
    }

    function start() {
        $(".radio-wz-open-hidden").bind("click", mouseHandler);
    }
    $(document).ready(start);

});
</script>

<div id="radio-wz">
    <div id="radio-wz-hide">
        <div class="radio-wz-open-hidden"></div>    
    </div><!-- end #radio-wz-hide -->
    <div id="radio-wz-col">
        <div id="radio-wz-source">
            <div id="radio" style="height:54px; width:1190px;"></div>
        </div><!-- end #radio-wz-source -->
    </div><!-- end #radio-wz-col -->
</div><!-- end #radio-wz -->

<!-- ContBack -->
<div id="contback">
<div id="slider">
    <div id="slider-full">
        <ul>
            <li data-transition="random" data-masterspeed="1500" data-delay="10000" data-thumb="http://radiobreakout.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/nonestophitz.jpg">
                <img src="http://radiobreakout.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/nonestophitz.jpg" alt="NONSTOP HITS" data-kenburns="on" data-duration="15000" data-ease="Linear.easeNone" data-bgfit="110" data-bgfitend="100">
                <div class="sld-bg"></div>
                <div class="tp-caption" data-x="20" data-speed="1100" data-start="1500" data-easing="Linear.easeNone" data-endspeed="500" data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn" style="z-index:3; max-width:350px; white-space: normal !important;">
                    <div class="sld-full">
                        <div class="sld-full-title">NONSTOP HITS</div>
                            <div class="sld-full-desc"></div>
                            <div class="sld-full-date">Wednesday, 18 November 2015</div>
                        </div>
                </div><!-- end .tp-caption -->
            </li><!-- end li.slide -->
            <li data-transition="random" data-masterspeed="1500" data-delay="10000" data-thumb="http://radiobreakout.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/melbourne.jpg">
                <img src="http://radiobreakout.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/melbourne.jpg" alt="Melbourne Slide" data-kenburns="on" data-duration="15000" data-ease="Linear.easeNone" data-bgfit="110" data-bgfitend="100">
                <div class="sld-bg"></div>
                <div class="tp-caption" data-x="20" data-speed="1100" data-start="1500" data-easing="Linear.easeNone" data-endspeed="500" data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn" style="z-index:3; max-width:350px; white-space: normal !important;">
                    <div class="sld-full">
                        <div class="sld-full-title">Melbourne Slide</div>
                            <div class="sld-full-desc"></div>
                            <div class="sld-full-date">Wednesday, 18 November 2015</div>
                        </div>
                </div><!-- end .tp-caption -->
            </li><!-- end li.slide -->
            <li data-transition="random" data-masterspeed="1500" data-delay="10000" data-thumb="http://radiobreakout.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/sydey-1300x580.jpeg">
                <img src="http://radiobreakout.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/sydey-1300x580.jpeg" alt="Shows" data-kenburns="on" data-duration="15000" data-ease="Linear.easeNone" data-bgfit="110" data-bgfitend="100">
                <div class="sld-bg"></div>
                <div class="tp-caption" data-x="20" data-speed="1100" data-start="1500" data-easing="Linear.easeNone" data-endspeed="500" data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn" style="z-index:3; max-width:350px; white-space: normal !important;">
                    <div class="sld-full">
                        <div class="sld-full-title">Shows</div>
                            <div class="sld-full-desc">shows</div>
                            <div class="sld-full-date">Wednesday, 18 November 2015</div>
                        </div>
                </div><!-- end .tp-caption -->
            </li><!-- end li.slide -->  
        </ul>
    </div><!-- end #slider-full -->
</div><!-- end #slider -->
```

Comment: try making it even more negative. `z-index:-9999;`

Comment: a fiddle will help, best thing for CSS issues :)

Comment: Negative z-index is not good practice. You have got millions of positive values

Comment: Likely reason: header and slider are in different stacking contexts.

Comment: I am investigating the code, a hard task, and I see that header is good closed and then comes the contback. Something more than this explanation is happening. Please, make a jsfiddle.net to show us the problem

Comment: I'm guessing now but maybe setting `position:fixed; left:0; right:0` for header is something what you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

The opacity is changing your stacking order so in this case z-index is not  usefull. Check this link for more info.
http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.